# IsInRole - Error Invalid column name 'UserId'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

This is an MVC4 project using SimpleMembership with EntityFramework First approach.
I am getting 2 errors when I try to use User.IsInRole("Admin").

**1. Invalid column name "UserId".

 2. Invalid column name 'RoleId'.**

I suspect the reason is because I have a user class and respective table defined where the primary key field is called "Id" instead of "UserId" (which is the default in MVC4 template). This project is near its completion so I dont want to revert to using UserId unless I really really have to.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Intro { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

The primary key columns on the other simple membership tables are the defaults as follows

```
Users : Id
webpages_Membership : UserId
webpages_UsersInRoles : Users_Id
webpages_Roles : RoleId
```

All other membership functionality works currently fine. ie. Login, Register, OAuth Login etc.

If anyone can shed any light on this please do as it killing me at the moment!

Thanks

Comment: In your call to WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection did you modify the parameter userIdColumn to equal "Id"?  The default for webpages_UsersInRoles is "UserId", not "User_Id" and it should have a "RoleId" column. Where is User.IsInRole coming from? Is this a method you wrote? Why aren't you using SimpleRoleProvider.IsUserInRole?

Comment: Yes I do have a column RoleID on webpages_UsersInRoles but I also have a Users_Id column .. Ill try chnaging this to see what happens. I am using the default IPrincipal method User.IsInRole, is there another way to get this info?